# Begging the question in a proof by induction

Tags: induction

A friend of mine is just learning about proof by induction, and because I learned about it a while back and loved it I was helping her with some problems. The specific problem in question was to prove that

$2^n≤2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1$

for all $n$ is a positive integer.

When I got to showing the $k+1$ case I had that

$2×2^k≤2^{k+2}-2^k-1$

and then one can simply replace $2^k$ with the right side of the assumption and the rest ultimately evaluates to $2≥1$ which is true. I say this is a valid method if you are asking the question "when is what we're trying to show true?" and trying to simplify it from there. Her professor said this is begging the question, but as long as you ask the question and don't assume it to be true I don't see what the problem is.

To be more specific I ask when what I want to show is true, show it is true when $2≥1$ and thus it is always true (for $n$ is an integer).

Comment: Why don't you show your actual proof attempt rather than just describe the nature of it?

Comment: Your argument is not at all clear, perhaps because you are just sketching it loosely.  As it stands, there isn't enough detail to confirm or reject it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the argument you are going for is this:

The claim is clear for $n=1$ since $2≤4-1-1$.

Assume that we know the claim for $n=k$ .  Thus, assume that $$2^k≤2^{k+1}-2^{k-1}-1$$

We wish to show that this implies the claim for $n=k+1$.

Toward that end we write:  $$2^{k+1}=2\times 2^k≤2\times \left(2^{k+1}-2^{k-1}-1\right)=2^{k+2}-2^{k}-2<2^{k+2}-2^k-1$$  and we are done.

Comment: That is essentially what I meant. Thank you!